# Is there a way to hide the value of a 'global' variable passed through Event listener, while still letting the script run?

Tags: php, octobercms

I am creating a plugin on OctoberCMS, where the user can input a  code into a field in the plugin Settings menu. I've saved this input into a global variable, which I've pasted on the template for the pages.

In Plugin.php, the code for saving it into a global variable:

```
 public function boot()
{
    Event::listen('cms.page.beforeDisplay', function($controller, $url, $page) {

        $settings = Settings::instance();

        $script = $settings->script; 

        $controller->vars['script'] = $script;
    });
}
```

In the template.htm, calling the variable in the  tags:

```
{{ script | raw }}
```

which then displays the  code that was inputted, when inspecting the page.

My question is, is there a way for the actual value of the variable to be hidden but for the script to still run? So that any users who view the website won't be able to 'inspect' it and see what the script is. Thanks

Comment: And how should the script run then? If something should be used in the browser context, it **must** be accessible and can be inspected by anybody

Comment: The script itself is going to be a Google Analytics script, so wouldn't actually do anything for the user. But I figured as much. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @captiveCorsair You don't explicitly say what kind of script this is. JavaScripts are better to be put in an external file: <script src="examplescript.js">. This would make people have to go through some extra effort to see the script if they wanted to.

Comment: @PettisBrandon Thanks! That would probably be the only method to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do like  Google Analytics script does then you need to make script file.

> `your-javascript-file.js` now host it anywhere on other domain or on same site and copy its url.

now in your setting `$settings->script` for this variable, from back-end settings you can set value like.

```
<script src="https://your_site/something/your-javascript-file.js"></script>
```

so in your web page it will show something ^ like this but not actual code. user need to dig one step more to see actual code. but yes `in your web-page's source code only this single line will appear not js code it self.`

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that would be the only method to achieve a sort of "hidden" js